# Call an item when it is added to an array automatically?

Tags: python, arrays, items

I am trying to figure out a way to set a variable equal to elements of an array as they are added using a while loop. Any ideas how?

```
    __author__ = 'Noah'

    numbercount= input('How many people are you texting?')
    #turns numbercount into an integer
    numberint = int(numbercount)

    numberArray = []

    while len(numberArray)<numberint*10:
        newNumber = input('Enter each number, followed by "ENTER".')
        numberString = str(newNumber)
        numberArray.append(numberString)
        toaddrs = numberArray[0]
```

I am trying to set `toaddrs` equal to multiple items as the items are added to the array `numberArray`.

Comment: Can you give more detail about your expected input and output?

Comment: why not use a for loop

Comment: In what way is your existing code not working? And in what way is your title relevant to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Using a `for var in range(start, end, step)` instead of `while len(numberArray)<numberint*10:` and then replace `toaddrs = numberArray[0]` with `toaddrs = numberArray[var]`. For loops instantiate a variable that increments every iteration this way you can always have the most recent element be equal to `toaddrs`.

Please let me know if i'm misunderstanding.